# Problem involving Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

The following problems is from Durrett 3.4.9:

> Suppose $X_i$ are independent and $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$. Assume that 
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> P(X_m = m) &= P(X_m = -m) = m^{-2}/2, \text{ and }\\
> P(X_m = 1) &= P(X_m = -1) = (1 - m^{-2})/2.
> \end{split}
> $$
>   Show that $$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to \chi.$$

My attempt:

The expectation is $0$, and $EX_m^2 = 2 - 1/m^2 < \infty$. Thus, $\varphi(t) = 1 - (2 - 1/m^2) \frac{t^2}{2} + o(t^2)$.
Sum $X_m$ up and divided by $\sqrt{n}$, we get:
$$
\varphi_\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}(t)
  = \prod_{m = 1}^n 1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{2m^2}\right) \frac{t^2}{n} + o(n^{-1})
$$
Using the lemma: If
$$
\max_{1\le j\le n}\left|c_{j,n}\right|\to 0,
\sum_{j=1}^n c_{j,n} \to \lambda, \text{ and }
\sup_n \sum_{j=1}^n \left|c_{j,n}\right| < \infty
$$
then
$$\prod_{j=1}^n (1 + c_{j,n}) \to e^\lambda.$$
The characteristic function becomes:
$$\varphi_\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}(t) = e^{-t^2}.  $$
But then, it converges weakly to ${\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \chi$ rather than $\chi$.

Can any one help pointing out the mistake in the above reasoning?
Thank you!

Comment: Isn't $EX_m^2=2-1/m^2$? Also I think there are some parentheses missing: $P(X_m=1)=(1-m^{-2})/2$, so that the probabilities sum to 1.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Also, to be clear: you are using $\chi$ as a symbol for the standard normal distribution? This may not be the clearest or more common notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be in your asymptotic expansion of $\phi_m(t)$ (for $t\to 0$), that you then use to approximate the product $\prod_{m=1}^n \phi_m\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$.

Namely, you write
$$
\phi_m(t) = 1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{2m^2}\right)t^2 +o(t^2).
$$
This is correct, *for $m$ fixed and as $t\to 0$*. But now, you use it for $\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}$ (which indeed goes to $0$) in a product *from $m$ ranging from $1$ to $n$*: $m$ is *not* a fixed parameter anymore, there is a relation between the asymptotics of $\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $m$...

Let us look at the actual expression of $\phi_m$: after an easy computation,
$$
\phi_m(t) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{m^2}\right) \cos t + \frac{1}{m^2}\cos(mt)
$$
and when doing [a Taylor expansion (with respect to $t$),](http://goo.gl/Z7J1PK) the fourth order term has a quadratic dependence on $m$:
$$
\phi_m(t) = 1-\left(1 - \frac{1}{2m^2}\right) t^2+\frac{1}{24}\left(m^2+1-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)t^4 + o(t^5).
$$
While this does look innocuous, it is *not*: recall that you use then this expression evaluated on $\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}$, so that the fourth order term brings in $\frac{t^4}{n^2}$. But the product $\prod_{m=1}^n \phi_m\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ is for $m$ up to $n$, and when $m=n$ (and similar when $m$ is roughly close to $n$) we get
$$
\frac{1}{24}\left(m^2+1-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)\frac{t^4}{n^2} = \Theta(t^4).
$$
This is a constant/term that you neglected; but **cannot** neglect...

---

*As a side note: looking at [the exercise statement you mention](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) (Exercise 3.4.9, p.113 in the edition linked), there is this note: "The trouble here is that $X_{n,m}=\frac{X_m}{\sqrt{n}}$
does not satisfy (ii) of Theorem 3.4.5." Checking (the proof of) this theorem, (ii) is the hypothesis used to guarantee that the product of the characteristic functions is indeed well-approximated by the  product of their second-order Taylor expansion.*

Comment: Thank you! It's clear and helps me a lot to clarify the proof of CLT for triangular arrays.

Comment: Glad this helped!